# Statistics/Facets on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a little problem with facets in elasticsearch.
I have a table videos, a table channels, 1 channel has many videos.
I just want to show a donut with % of views_count per channel on the X lastest videos.

In SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(views_count) FROM videos WHERE videos.channel_id = X ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT Y
```

I can do that on all videos but I don't arrive to do that with the LIMIT. Any Idea??
Thanks

Comment: Reposted from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/elasticsearch/-lQsU4k0sNU

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to limit your facet to the latest e.g 100 videos?

I don't *think* this is possible, so the limitation should have to be done at the query (or facet_filter), setting a range for the data to be considered:

```
{
    "facets": {
        "views_count": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "videos.channel_id"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "from": 0, 
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "published_at" : { 
                "from" : <some_start_date>
            }
        }
    }
}
```